# How do I get the desired output in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I need some assistance, I'm working on creating a weekly schedule. But my output is not displaying the desired criteria. Everything is displaying, but it's not assigning the start and end time properly and I can't figure out why. I'm new to ruby so any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the method from my control and the output in the view.

```
 def generate_schedule
        logger.info @generate_schedules
    # create hash for view
        @generate_schedules = Hash.new
    # find current required schedule
        schedule_structure = Availability.where(:addressable_type      =>'CallCenter',:addressable_id => session[:employee].call_centers.first.id).all
    # find all available employee times
        employee_availability = Availability.where('priority > 0').where(:addressable_type => 'Employee', :addressable_id => session[:employee].call_centers.first.employees.collect(&:id)).all
    # create availability to requirement hash to determine order of days
        availability_to_requirement_hash = create_availability_to_requirement_hash(schedule_structure, employee_availability)
    # iterate through the hash day by day, a data is no use to us
        availability_to_requirement_hash.each do |day,a|
      # select the employees with availability for the chosen day, sort them by priority, and then iterate through them to clear the requirements
          employee_availability.select{|b| b.day_increment == day}.sort_by{|c| c.priority}.group_by(&:addressable).each do |employee, availabilities|
        # select the start time for the current day defined from requirement hash
          start_time = schedule_structure.select{|b| b.day_increment == day && b.priority > 0}.first.time_increment
        #define the length of the shift
          shift_length = employee.length_of_shift > availabilities.length ? availabilities.length : employee.length_of_shift
        #define the end time for the shift
          end_time = start_time + shift_length
          logger.info end_time
        #check if employee already defined in hash, if present add the shift as   an array of date, start time and end time, if not then add employee to hash with value as array
          @generate_schedules.has_key?(employee) ? @generate_schedules[employee] << [day, start_time, end_time] : @generate_schedules[employee] = [[day, start_time, end_time]]
          logger.info schedule_structure
        #update the schedule structure to reflect the time removed // do not change database
          (1..shift_length).each do |d|
            schedule_structure.select{|e| e.day_increment == day && e.priority > 0}.first.priority -= 1
            end
          end
        end
      end
```

Here's an example of my output:

[Example of View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLV9M.png)

Comment: Add your view file ?

Comment: Chris, first thing - please learn to format your questions properly so other people don't have to clean it up!